# Find a java class that extends an abstract class

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

How would I find a class that extends another abstract class?

Currently I have this:

```
public PluginFinder(ClassLoader cl, File f) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    super(new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL()}, cl);
    Class<?> jarClass = Class.forName("com.ngxdev.demoplugin.main.MainClass", true, this);
    this.instance = new PluginParser(jarClass).instance;
}
```

It works, but it's static, I need to find that "com.ngxdev.demoplugin.main.MainClass" without specifying it because the location can be "com.example.ExampleClass" for all I know.

I tried to use:
        `Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");`
but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to find all classes in your classpath which are subtypes of a given class?

Comment: if you're using an IDE, there is usually a find in all files option, you could search the abstract class name on all files and see what you get.

Comment: No no no, I'm making a plugin loader and I need to find a class that extends Plugin

Comment: A random class? All classes? A specific class?

Comment: All classes that extend Plugin - in a jar

Comment: [`Reflections` can do that.](https://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/index.html?org/reflections/Reflections.html)

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to use it, and it's an external jar file!

Comment: `Reflections` has a number of constructors. You can configure it to scan whatever you want. The javadoc is there. It's all there.

Comment: It can scan files, that's what I was missing! Okay I will answer this question myself

Comment: If you're making a plugin loader, why not use the [SerivceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class which is specifically designed for loading plugins dynamically?

Comment: Going to look into that @VGR

Answer (score 0):

`Reflections` can also scan files, for example:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new File("/plugin/example.jar"));
```

Using [this](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) libary